# How to design a shape like a bit curvy overlay flap using CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need a shape like the following:

[image: overlay flap design]

I made one using a single container and CSS3 pseudo classes:

```css
.overlay-flap {
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
.overlay-flap:before,
.overlay-flap:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.overlay-flap:before {
  width: 11px;
  height: 23px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  -o-transform: rotate(-35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  transform: rotate(-35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  left: -4px;
}
.overlay-flap:after {
  width: 11px;
  height: 23px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  -moz-transform: rotate(35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  -o-transform: rotate(35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  transform: rotate(35deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(0);
  right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-flap">content</div>
```

How can I make it the way I want, a bit curvy on the both sides? It'd be better if we can stick with a single container (HTML element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this i used svg

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
    <path d="m 20 20 q 30 15 30 30 l 0 100 h 150 v -100 q 0 -15 30 -30">
```

If you don't want fill try this

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
        <path d="m 20 20 q 30 15 30 30 l 0 100 h 150 v -100 q 0 -15 30 -30" fill="none" stroke="grey">
```

Answer (score 0):

Following shape css will create shape like you want.

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XXbJ5/32/)

```css
#main {
    height: 250px;
    left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 255px;
}
#bg-bottom {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
}
#bg {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 232px;
}
#top {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -130px;
    width: 230px;
}
#bottom {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 100px;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="bg-bottom"></div>
<div id="bg">
    
    <div id="top"></div>
        
</div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help.

**Edited:**

Another way is using border.

```
#bg::before {
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    content: "";
    left: -9px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 10%;
}
#bg::after {
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    top: 0;
    width: 11%;
}
```

Updated [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/XXbJ5/34/)

Comment: it's an overkill. :(

Comment: @MayeenulIslam Sorry means?

Comment: I mentioned in my question: *It'd be better if we can stick with a single container (HTML element).* :)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I don't think it's possible with only single element.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I edited my answer with I remove extra 2 div and created.